# How do I create a "Choose Dialog" in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In the Apple Human Interface Guidelines, there's a section about [Choose Dialogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowDialogs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH43-SW1), which are distinct from Open Dialogs:

> By default, the dialog’s title is “Choose.” If, for example, the
>   command that displays the dialog is Choose Picture, title the dialog
>   “Choose Picture.” If it’s helpful, also change the Choose button to
>   something more specific.

However, I've been unable to find any documentation on how to create one, as opposed to a regular `NSOpenPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel=[NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setTitle: @"Choose File"];
[openPanel setPrompt: @"Choose"];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories: YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles: NO];
if ([openPanel runModal] != NSCancelButton)
    {
    // Use -[openPanel URL]...
    }
```

Comment: But isn't this just an open dialog that's configured to have the same prompts as a choose dialog?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.  Configure an open dialog to be a "choose" dialog as recommended by the Human Interface Guidelines.  The way I read it, they are emphasising _choosing_ a file (or folder in my example) rather than _opening_ it.  The mechanics of the panel are the same, just the labels change.  I do not believe there needs to be a different class, although you could make a MyChoosePanel with defaults similar to the above.